# Can't set custom dependency property within a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've written a custom control that contains a number of dependency properties. Everything works fine if I use XAML such as this:

```
<ProgressDial DialStart="Top" OutlineColor="Red" ... />
```

However I run into a problem if I try to set the properties from within a style, i.e.:-

```
<Style x:Key="ProgressDialStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ProgressDial}">
    <Setter Property="DialStart" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="OutlineColor" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

All but one of the DPs can be set fine - for some reason the `DialStart` property setter gets a squiggle under it in the XAML editor, with this message:

> The property "DialStart" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "DialStart". For attached properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetDialStart" and "SetDialStart" methods.

If I try to run the application I get a XamlParseException with this message:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property

Intellisense is "seeing" the DP fine - `DialStart` appears in the list of available properties, and I can call up the available values (DialStart is an enum by the way).

Here's the `DialStart` DP code from my user control:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DialStartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DialStartProperty",
        typeof(DialStart),
        typeof(ProgressDial),
        new PropertyMetadata(DialStart.Top));

    public DialStart DialStart
    {
        get { return (DialStart)GetValue(DialStartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DialStartProperty, value); }
    }
```

The `DialStart` type is an enum, by the way.

And here's an example of one of the other DPs that *is* happy being set from within a style:-

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "OutlineColor",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(ProgressDial),
        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke)));

    public Brush OutlineColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(OutlineColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutlineColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

I've tried replacing the `DialStart` property with separate GetDialStart() and SetDialStart() methods, but it made no difference. (On a side-note, I'm curious why there are two ways to expose a DP?).

Comment: register it as `"DialStart"`, not `Register("DialStartProperty"`

Comment: Typical - just spotted that (after an hour of head scratching) and was about to delete my SO question when I noticed your comment! Always the way...

Comment: Use C# shortcut to avoid these syntax annoying problems;
Type "propdp" and press "tab". This is the shortcut for automatic creation dependency property.